# Iterate through JSON data, create dict/list and then insert into Postgresql database using psycopg2?

Tags: python, json, postgresql, dictionary

This is a multipart issue I am working on. Yes, I am quite new to Python, so I may not express things correctly.

Trying to figure out how I would accomplish iterating through some JSON data that I am pulling from an API to extract the values and then I believe I need to either create a dict or list of the data I want to then push "INSERT INTO" a PostgreSQL database.

This is the JSON data I pull from a device:

```
{u'service_group_stat': {u'cur_conns': 344,
                         u'member_stat_list': [{u'cur_conns': 66,
                                                u'req_bytes': 1476212423,
                                                u'req_pkts': 10449342,
                                                u'resp_bytes': 33132743858,
                                                u'resp_pkts': 25652317,
                                                u'server': u'WWW0006',
                                                u'tot_conns': 172226},
                                               {u'cur_conns': 64,
                                                u'req_bytes': 1666275823,
                                                u'req_pkts': 11982676,
                                                u'resp_bytes': 37575461036,
                                                u'resp_pkts': 29175599,
                                                u'server': u'WWW0005',
                                                u'tot_conns': 205244},
                                               {u'cur_conns': 89,
                                                u'req_bytes': 1671222671,
                                                u'req_pkts': 11940864,
                                                u'resp_bytes': 37064038202,
                                                u'resp_pkts': 28747313,
                                                u'server': u'WWW0004',
                                                u'tot_conns': 195789},
                                               {u'cur_conns': 37,
                                                u'req_bytes': 94117510958,
                                                u'req_pkts': 585916896,
                                                u'resp_bytes': 1860691638618,
                                                u'resp_pkts': 1439228725,
                                                u'server': u'WWW0003',
                                                u'tot_conns': 7366402},
                                               {u'cur_conns': 42,
                                                u'req_bytes': 98580368121,
                                                u'req_pkts': 642797814,
                                                u'resp_bytes': 1934241923560,
                                                u'resp_pkts': 1498242871,
                                                u'server': u'WWW0002',
                                                u'tot_conns': 7221995},
                                               {u'cur_conns': 46,
                                                u'req_bytes': 94886760323,
                                                u'req_pkts': 593577169,
                                                u'resp_bytes': 1863028601218,
                                                u'resp_pkts': 1441197389,
                                                u'server': u'WWW0001',
                                                u'tot_conns': 7260787}],
                         u'name': u'SG_SITE1.BUSINESS.COM_443',
                         u'req_bytes': 292398350319,
                         u'req_pkts': 1856664761,
                         u'resp_bytes': 5765734406492,
                         u'resp_pkts': 4462244214,
                         u'tot_conns': 22422443}}
```

It's stored as "data".

So then I thought something like this would be needed:

```
for row in data['service_group_stat']['member_stat_list']:
    SRVR_NAME = row['server']
    CURR_CONNS = row['cur_conns']
    TOTAL_CONNS = row['tot_conns']
    REQ_BYTES = row['req_bytes']
    REQ_PKTS = row['req_pkts']
    RESP_BYTES = row['resp_bytes']
    RESP_PKTS = row['resp_pkts']
```

The goal is to extract the metrics for each server in that list.

Essentially I am looking to extract the following and insert into a database:

```
SRVR_NAME  CURR_CONNS  TOT_CONNS  REQ_BYTES   REQ_PKTS  RESP_BYTES   RESP_PKTS
WWW00006    66         172226     1476212423  10449342  33132743858  25652317
WWW00005    64         205244     1666275823  11982676  37575461036  29175599
WWW00004    89         195789     1671222671  11940864  37064038202  28747313
WWW00003    37         7366402    94117510958 585916896 1860691638618 1439228725
```

I'm not sure if I should try to read the details for one server, create a dict based on the values for that single server and then insert one server at a time into the database?

Something like:

```
# Create DICT of server metrics from JSON data

metrics = ({"SRVR_NAME":'SRVR_NAME', "CURR_CONNS":'CURR_CONNS',
             "TOTAL_CONNS":'TOTAL_CONNS', "REQ_BYTES":'REQ_BYTES', "REQ_PKTS":'REQ_PKTS', "RESP_BYTES":'RESP_BYTES',
             "RESP_PKTS":'RESP_PKTS'})

# Execute storing metrics for server
# Table: metrics    Fields:(SRVR_NAME, CURR_CONNS, TOTAL_CONNS, REQ_BYTES, REQ_PKTS, RESP_BYTES, RESP_PKTS)

# Using psycopg2 to interact with PostgreSQL

cur.executemany("""INSERT INTO metrics("SRVR_NAME", "CURR_CONNS", "TOTAL_CONNS", "REQ_BYTES", 
                    "REQ_PKTS", "RESP_BYTES", "RESP_PKTS") VALUES (%(SRVR_NAME)s, %(DATE)s, %(TIME)s, %(CURR_CONNS)s, 
                    %(TOTAL_CONNS)s, %(REQ_BYTES)s, %(REQ_PKTS)s, %(RESP_BYTES)s, %(RESP_PKTS)s)""", metrics)
```

I think that's close to how I might be able to do the metrics for a single server at a time?

Haven't figured the whole thing out yet but I think it's close.

But the real question is going to be can I build a bigger list or dict containing all the details for each server and then doing a bulk insert?  Or maybe I iterate through the new dict/list and insert through each pass / iteration of that dict/list?

Hope this makes sense.  Just not good at concisely breaking this down and explaining.

Hoping to understand the most efficient way to accomplish this.

---

UPDATE #1

Using some of the code suggested I am trying to use the following:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
date = str(now.strftime("%m-%d-%Y"))
time = str(now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

# Define a DICT/LIST of ServiceGroup names that we will pull stats for

name = 'SG_ACCOUNT.BUSINESS.COM_443'

# Pull stats from A10 LB for ServiceGroup and store in memory
# Will want to eventually iterate through a DICT/LIST of SG names

data = c.slb.service_group.stats(name)

srv = """INSERT INTO server("SG_NAME", "SRVR_NAME") VALUES ('name', %(server)s)"""
argslist1 = data[u'service_group_stat'][u'member_stat_list']
psycopg2.extras.execute_batch(cur, srv, argslist1, page_size=100)

sql = """INSERT INTO metrics("SRVR_NAME", "DATE", "TIME", "CURR_CONNS", "TOTAL_CONNS", 
                             "REQ_BYTES", "REQ_PKTS", "RESP_BYTES", 
                             "RESP_PKTS") VALUES (%(server)s, 
             'date', 'time', %(curr_conns)s, %(total_conns)s, 
             %(req_bytes)s, %(req_pkts)s, %(resp_bytes)s, %(resp_pkts)s)"""
argslist2 = data[u'service_group_stat'][u'member_stat_list']
psycopg2.extras.execute_batch(cur, sql, argslist2, page_size=100)
```

However it's failing because I can't seem to pull in previously declared values such as:

```
date = str(now.strftime("%m-%d-%Y"))
time = str(now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
name = 'SG_ACCOUNT.BUSINESS.COM_443'
```

I get the following error when trying to insert the 'name'

```
DETAIL:  Key (SG_NAME)=(name) is not present in table "servicegroup".
```

I don't think it's actually pulling the value defined for 'name' and is instead trying to INSERT "name" which doesn't exist in the "servicegroup" table.

Comment: I think you should skip the Python json manipulation and do it in Postgresql in instead. If nobody answers until tomorrow I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#module-psycopg2.extras it says that `.executemany` is not the most performant. An alternative is `execute_batch()` in http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers

```
import psycopg2.extras
cur = conn.cursor()
sql = """INSERT INTO metrics("SRVR_NAME", "CURR_CONNS", "TOTAL_CONNS", 
                             "REQ_BYTES", "REQ_PKTS", "RESP_BYTES", 
                             "RESP_PKTS") VALUES (%(srvr_name)s, 
             %(date)s, %(time)s, %(curr_conns)s, %(total_conns)s, 
             %(req_bytes)s, %(req_pkts)s, %(resp_bytes)s, %(resp_pkts)s)"""
argslist = data[u'service_group_stat'][u'member_stat_list']
psycopg2.extras.execute_batch(cur, sql, argslist, page_size=100)
```

Here `argslist` is gotten by `data[u'service_group_stat'][u'member_stat_list']` and looks like:

```
[{u'cur_conns': 66,
  u'req_bytes': 1476212423,
  u'req_pkts': 10449342,
  u'resp_bytes': 33132743858L,
  u'resp_pkts': 25652317,
  u'server': u'WWW0006',
  u'tot_conns': 172226},
 {u'cur_conns': 64,
  u'req_bytes': 1666275823,
  u'req_pkts': 11982676,
  u'resp_bytes': 37575461036L,
  u'resp_pkts': 29175599,
  u'server': u'WWW0005',
  u'tot_conns': 205244},
 {u'cur_conns': 89,
  u'req_bytes': 1671222671,
  u'req_pkts': 11940864,
  u'resp_bytes': 37064038202L,
  u'resp_pkts': 28747313,
  u'server': u'WWW0004',
  u'tot_conns': 195789},
 {u'cur_conns': 37,
  u'req_bytes': 94117510958L,
  u'req_pkts': 585916896,
  u'resp_bytes': 1860691638618L,
  u'resp_pkts': 1439228725,
  u'server': u'WWW0003',
  u'tot_conns': 7366402},
 {u'cur_conns': 42,
  u'req_bytes': 98580368121L,
  u'req_pkts': 642797814,
  u'resp_bytes': 1934241923560L,
  u'resp_pkts': 1498242871,
  u'server': u'WWW0002',
  u'tot_conns': 7221995},
 {u'cur_conns': 46,
  u'req_bytes': 94886760323L,
  u'req_pkts': 593577169,
  u'resp_bytes': 1863028601218L,
  u'resp_pkts': 1441197389,
  u'server': u'WWW0001',
  u'tot_conns': 7260787}]
```

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. That seems pretty efficient.  I need to go read up on that and see if I can try it.  Thank you!

Comment: Yeah so it seems despite my length post I failed to mention something that appears to impact the use of that arglist.  I have to insert date and time as they are not part of that data.  :-(

Comment: Oh what's that?

Comment: I think thats why I was going down the path of basically rebuilding the data pulled into a new dict or list.  Then I could insert date and time for each.  Then I could pass that new dict as arglist maybe?

Comment: It looks ok to me. It is a list of dicts as is specified. Are you getting any errors when you run this?

Comment: It's failing when trying to use variables defined outside of the data.  I updated my question with more details about this and trying to use the code.  I think it will work, pretty sure we are close. But I'm concerned about how to pull in those variables?

Comment: Well now you have two queries, haha.

Comment: Yeah but even just the original one wouldn't work due to the date and time. I have to somehow get that inserted also.

Comment: Are you storing the date and time as strings in your database?

Comment: dankeschoen @BrifordWylie